# CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am compiling build.py, and getting the error below:

```
(env)$ python build.py
```

the errors:

```
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

cffi.VerificationError: CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing build dependencies. gcc at the least.

Comment: @PaulWhipp I have installed gcc! But still have problem

Comment: At quick glance, it *appears* to stem from a missing header file: `No such file or directory 12 | #include "cuda.h"`. Which, given the quotes, is a local header file, *not* a system header; which should make tracking it down a bit easier.

Comment: @S3DEV thank you for your response! I installed cuda, and I am receiving these below errors!


/home/amirabb/anaconda3/envs/deep9/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /lib64/libpthread.so.0

/home/amirabb/anaconda3/envs/deep9/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

distutils.errors.LinkError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

cffi.VerificationError: LinkError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Research this: `cannot find /lib64/libpthread.so.0`.